# compare multiple strings using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have several xml files I download from affiliate sites, all containing product information which I then store in a mysql database.

what I would like to do next is find out if different suppliers offer the same product, i.e.

**supplier 1 products:**

1. Adidas F5 Firm Ground Football Boots - Mens
2. Adidas Nitrocharge 4 Firm Ground Football Boots - Mens
3. Adidas 11Nova Artificial Ground Football Boots - Mens
4. Nike Elastico Ii Astro Turf Football Boots - Boys
5. New Balance Furon Dispatch Astro Turf Football Boots - Mens

**supplier 2 products:**

1. Mens New Balance Furon Dispatch Astro Turf soccer cleats
2. Mens 11Nova Artificial Ground soccer cleats Adidas
3. Boys Adidas F5 Firm Ground soccer cleats

**supplier 3 products:**
more of the same

SO supplier 1 - product 5, and supplier 2 - product 1, are actually the same product but the descriptions are slightly different. The product may also exist in supplier 3, but with a different description again.

using php and mysql I need to find the most efficient way to get all matching products as there are thousands

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is a bit vague. What code have you tried? How is your DB setup? Like when you import, does it force unique names?

Answer (score 0):

In your database have the name you want to display as one of your fields then use a text field to have a ; separated field of keywords that if matched designate that item as the same, call it search_needles or something.